# Disallow horizontal recyclerview to listen to vertical swipe gesture

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, gesture, gesturedetector

My fragment view implements a touch listener to listen to various gestures but my horizontally fashioned recyclerview consumes any gesture performed over it.

Basically I want to listen to vertical swipe when performed over recyclerview but I never receive callback in fragment view's gesture detector.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get a workaround for it. I had to subclass ViewGroup and override onInterceptTouchEvent and handle things using MotionEvent.{action_type}. Then I replaced the fragment view's parent view group with this custom view group inside xml layout.

So in nutshell, if I detect it as a vertical swipe I return true in my onInterceptTouchEvent otherwise false. If its false, the touch event is passed onto the child views for handling. Works perfect.